# Working with Multiple XML Schema Classes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, schema

I'm working with a data import process in C#, which takes a zip file filled with XML files and saves specific data points into a database.  This is accomplished by loading the XML data into classes compiled from the schema.  The import logic retrieves the data by digging down into the right classes and fields.

The XML schema is defined by a different company, and the schema changes every one to years when an updated version of their software is released.  What my company would like to do is be able to import different versions of the schema so that we could support older files.  There is also debate on whether this change is worth the effort.

My plan to accomplish this would be to determine which schema to use at the beginning of an import, and then use different interfacing classes to get the data from the XML and pass it back to the import classes, which would then save the values to the database.  There are over 200 classes generated based on the schema, but we only need to access data in about half of them.

Are there other ways to approach supporting multiple XML schemas that may be easier?

Comment: Do the various XML schemas each map to their own set of data objects, or will they all map to a single universal set of data objects? Are you looking to reuse code between different schema versions or is it satisfactory to have a new code base for each new 'version'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put each set of classes of a schema into an assembly of its own. Then, load the right assembly dynamically at runtime after you identified the schema version. This technique is often used to create plug-ins (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6334/Plug-ins-in-C) for an example).

To avoid the need of having all of your 200 classes implementing an interface, your import code can make use of the C# 4.0 `dynamic` keyword for accessing schema objects, regardless from which assembly they are loaded, as long as the method signature does not change between versions. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62839/Adventures-with-C-4-0-dynamic-ExpandoObject-Elasti) for an example.

The drawback is that you will loose type-safety, you will have to decide if this is  acceptable in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This looks like a great solution, since you are right that the signatures do not change between versions.  If there are new fields in a newer version, it would be easy enough to only access those fields based the schema version.  The original version of this was written in .NET 3.5, so using a dynamic namespace was not an option.